# Star (*) notation in R session Information

Tags: r, session, devtools

I'm using R's `devtools::session_info()` to print session information, which gives below output.

[image]

What does star (*) indicate next to the name of library?

Comment: In general, when you have a question about a specific function, look for the help. On the console, this is commonly done with `?functionname` or `?package::functionname`. If you are not certain of the exact name but know it's around somewhere, try `help.search("functionname")`, which will find functions with close/fuzzy matches to that name. Two (of *many*) good online resources are https://www.rdocumentation.org/ and https://rseek.org/. And while Ronak's answer appears to address what you asked, please do a little bit of own-research before asking questions on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

From `?devtools::session_info()`

> *: whether the package is attached to the search path

You can find the search path by using `search()`. For example for me it shows as

```
search()

# [1] ".GlobalEnv"           "package:janitor"      "package:xts"          "package:zoo"         
# [5] "package:nycflights13" "package:lubridate"    "package:ggrepel"      "package:data.table"  
# [9] "package:matrixStats"  "package:forcats"      "package:stringr"      "package:purrr"       
#[13] "package:readr"        "package:tidyr"        "package:tibble"       "package:ggplot2"     
#[17] "package:tidyverse"    "package:dplyr"        "tools:rstudio"        "package:stats"       
#[21] "package:graphics"     "package:grDevices"    "package:utils"        "package:datasets"    
#[25] "package:methods"      "Autoloads"            "package:base"
```

To find a function it goes through this list. [This](https://r-pkgs.org/namespace.html#search-path) might be a good read to understand search path.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to mark "other attached packages", as described in `sessionInfo`, or "*: whether the package is attached to the search path", as the docs formulate it. For example, `session_info` returns the following before a call to `library(tidyverse)`:

```r
 package     * version date       lib source        
 assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 backports     1.1.4   2019-04-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 callr         3.2.0   2019-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 cli           1.1.0   2019-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 crayon        1.3.4   2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 desc          1.2.0   2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 devtools      2.0.2   2019-04-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 digest        0.6.18  2018-10-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 fs            1.3.0   2019-05-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 glue          1.3.1   2019-03-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 magrittr      1.5     2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 memoise       1.1.0   2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 pkgbuild      1.0.3   2019-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 pkgload       1.0.2   2018-10-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 prettyunits   1.0.2   2015-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 processx      3.3.0   2019-03-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 ps            1.3.0   2018-12-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 R6            2.4.0   2019-02-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 Rcpp          1.0.1   2019-03-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 remotes       2.0.4   2019-04-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 rlang         0.3.4   2019-04-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 rprojroot     1.3-2   2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 rstudioapi    0.10    2019-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 usethis       1.5.0   2019-04-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 withr         2.1.2   2018-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
```

After calling `library(tidyverse)` it returns this:

```r
 package     * version date       lib source        
 assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 backports     1.1.4   2019-04-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 broom         0.5.2   2019-04-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 callr         3.2.0   2019-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 cellranger    1.1.0   2016-07-27 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 cli           1.1.0   2019-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 colorspace    1.4-1   2019-03-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 crayon        1.3.4   2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 desc          1.2.0   2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 devtools      2.0.2   2019-04-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 digest        0.6.18  2018-10-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 dplyr       * 0.8.0.1 2019-02-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 forcats     * 0.4.0   2019-02-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 fs            1.3.0   2019-05-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 generics      0.0.2   2018-11-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 ggplot2     * 3.1.1   2019-04-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 glue          1.3.1   2019-03-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 gtable        0.3.0   2019-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 haven         2.1.0   2019-02-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 hms           0.4.2   2018-03-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 httr          1.4.0   2018-12-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 jsonlite      1.6     2018-12-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 lattice       0.20-38 2018-11-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 lazyeval      0.2.2   2019-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 lubridate     1.7.4   2018-04-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 magrittr      1.5     2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 memoise       1.1.0   2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 modelr        0.1.4   2019-02-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 munsell       0.5.0   2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 nlme          3.1-139 2019-04-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 pillar        1.3.1   2018-12-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 pkgbuild      1.0.3   2019-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 pkgconfig     2.0.2   2018-08-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 pkgload       1.0.2   2018-10-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 plyr          1.8.4   2016-06-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 prettyunits   1.0.2   2015-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 processx      3.3.0   2019-03-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 ps            1.3.0   2018-12-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 purrr       * 0.3.2   2019-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 R6            2.4.0   2019-02-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 Rcpp          1.0.1   2019-03-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 readr       * 1.3.1   2018-12-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 readxl        1.3.1   2019-03-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 remotes       2.0.4   2019-04-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 rlang         0.3.4   2019-04-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 rprojroot     1.3-2   2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 rstudioapi    0.10    2019-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 rvest         0.3.3   2019-04-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 scales        1.0.0   2018-08-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 stringi       1.4.3   2019-03-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 stringr     * 1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 tibble      * 2.1.1   2019-03-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 tidyr       * 0.8.3   2019-03-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 tidyselect    0.2.5   2018-10-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 tidyverse   * 1.2.1   2017-11-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 usethis       1.5.0   2019-04-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 withr         2.1.2   2018-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 xml2          1.2.0   2018-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
```

If you convert the `session_info` object into a regular dataframe, you'll see that the asterisks correspond to a logical vector `attached`:

```r
si <- devtools::session_info()
as.data.frame(si$packages) %>% select(package, attached)

#### OUTPUT ####

                package attached
assertthat   assertthat    FALSE
backports     backports    FALSE
broom             broom    FALSE
callr             callr    FALSE
cellranger   cellranger    FALSE
cli                 cli    FALSE
colorspace   colorspace    FALSE
crayon           crayon    FALSE
desc               desc    FALSE
devtools       devtools    FALSE
digest           digest    FALSE
dplyr             dplyr     TRUE
fansi             fansi    FALSE
forcats         forcats     TRUE
fs                   fs    FALSE
generics       generics    FALSE
ggplot2         ggplot2     TRUE
glue               glue    FALSE
gtable           gtable    FALSE
haven             haven    FALSE
hms                 hms    FALSE
httr               httr    FALSE
jsonlite       jsonlite    FALSE
lattice         lattice    FALSE
lazyeval       lazyeval    FALSE
lubridate     lubridate    FALSE
magrittr       magrittr    FALSE
memoise         memoise    FALSE
modelr           modelr    FALSE
munsell         munsell    FALSE
nlme               nlme    FALSE
pillar           pillar    FALSE
pkgbuild       pkgbuild    FALSE
pkgconfig     pkgconfig    FALSE
pkgload         pkgload    FALSE
plyr               plyr    FALSE
prettyunits prettyunits    FALSE
processx       processx    FALSE
ps                   ps    FALSE
purrr             purrr     TRUE
R6                   R6    FALSE
Rcpp               Rcpp    FALSE
readr             readr     TRUE
readxl           readxl    FALSE
remotes         remotes    FALSE
rlang             rlang    FALSE
rprojroot     rprojroot    FALSE
rstudioapi   rstudioapi    FALSE
rvest             rvest    FALSE
scales           scales    FALSE
sessioninfo sessioninfo    FALSE
stringi         stringi    FALSE
stringr         stringr     TRUE
tibble           tibble     TRUE
tidyr             tidyr     TRUE
tidyselect   tidyselect    FALSE
tidyverse     tidyverse     TRUE
usethis         usethis    FALSE
utf8               utf8    FALSE
withr             withr    FALSE
xml2               xml2    FALSE
```